# Can't get webpack-dev-server proxy and watch work together

Tags: php, proxy, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to get work together webpack and PHP.

The proxying to PHP built-in webserver works but it loses the ability to watch for changes on index.php and the rest of PHP files.
Watching js files works correct.

Package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.21",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.0"
  },
"scripts": {
    "backend": "cd src && php -S localhost:9000",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 3000 --content-base src",
    "start": "start npm run backend && start npm run server"
  }
```

webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/': {
            target: {
                host: "localhost",
                port: 9000,
                protocol: "http"
            }
        }
    },
},
watch: true,
```

Without a proxy the watch and livereload work correct (on index.html file).

How can I tell the webpack-dev-server to watch php files explicitly?

Maybe the way I'm using for getting the PHP proxying is wrong or too complicated? I'd like to hear for other solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, and it was painful :D

I would suggest you to use BrowserSync plugin. Install `browsersync` and then `browser-sync-webpack-plugin`, then all you have to do is require or import `browser-sync-webpack-plugin` in your `webpack` development config. Last step would be to add it in webpack config file as plugin ...

```
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      proxy: 'http://mylocalpage.loc/',
      tunnel: true,
      files: ['resources/', 'public/index.php']
    })
```

for more info visit [BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io/) and  [BrowserSyncWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/Va1/browser-sync-webpack-plugin).

Also I have `webpack.config.js` for development and `webpack.config.prod.js` for production, so `webpack-dev-server` uses default webpack.config. Also in my case `/resources` folder contains all my `.js` and `.sass` files.